# Solutions in field extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

I need some help with the following task:

Let $L/K$ be a finite field extension.

a) $[L:K]=41$, show that there exists an $a\in L$ such that $L=K[a]$.

b) $[L:K]=14$ and $f(x)=0$ with $deg(f(x))=3$. Assume that $f(x)=0$ has a solution in $L$ and show that $f(x)=0$ has a solution in $K$.

I'm not sure what to do,do I have to find a polynomial with degree 41? Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit: I think a) is supposed to be solved like this

$K \subset K[a] \subset  L$, $a\in L$. Since $a\notin K$ it's $K \neq K[a]$, so $[K[a]:K]>1$ and since $[K[a]: K] | [L:K]=41$, $[K[a]: K] \neq 1$ implies that $[K[a]:K]=41$, so $[L:K[a]]=1$ has to hold and $L=K[a]$.

Comment: What do you think is the key property of the number $41$ that might make this true? Can you give an example with a degree different from $41$ such that this does not hold?

Comment: Because 41 is a prime number? So an example would be a number which isn't prime and can be divided but I'm not sure how this helps us yet.

Comment: Indeed, it's because $41$ is prime. Try using this hint: you can actually take any $a$ which is not in $K$.

Comment: So it should work if we use $\Bbb{Q}$, $\Bbb{C}$, $f(x)=x^(41)+1$ and $a=(-1)^(1/41)$

Comment: Obviously $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Q}$ is not a finite extension, and in particular does not have degree $41$.

Comment: True, how about $\Bbb{Q}[x]/(f(x))$ instead of $\Bbb{C}$ then?

Comment: You seem to misunderstand the question, and my hint. You do not get to choose what $K$ and $L$ are. You have to show that, for any field extension of degree $41$, there is $a\in L$ such that $L=K[a]$. My hint is saying that in that situation, you can actually take any $a\in L$ which is not in $K$, and it will work (but you still have to prove that).

Comment: I think I got it, I edited it in the main post. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Your solution is good. Try to do the same kind of thing with the second question; assume some $a\in L$ is a solution, and look at the degrees.